# What do I do in the case of this double series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I am student who learns from examples, and I have yet to see what happens when two sums such as this one,

$$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{a=1}^2 \displaystyle\sum\limits_{b=a+1}^2 4\left[\left(\frac{1}{b-a}\right)^8 - \left(\frac{1}{b-a}\right)^4\right]$$

be solved. I am sure, when a = 1, the inner sum should solve itself like any "normal summation", but when a = 2, what happens? Do I skip the process of the inner summation; do I proceed with the inner sum, and if so, in what ways do I solve the inner sum; or do I solve this problem in a completely different way?

Comment: when the lower index is one greater than the upper index, then even in most general interpretations, the sum is $0$. Therefore, when $a=2$, the inner sum is $0$.

Comment: When would the inner sum not be 0?

Comment: I was speaking in more generality. If the upper limit is one less than the lower limit, *no terms* are included in the sum and *that* is why the sum is $0$. However, in *this* particular case, even when $a=1$ and $b=2$, the summand $4\left[\left(\frac1{2-1}\right)^8-\left(\frac1{2-1}\right)^4\right]$ is $0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thinking inductively on the upper and lower indices, we can think of a summation as a difference of two functions on the integers:
$$
\sum_{k=a}^bf(k)=F(b)-F(a-1)
$$
Even in this generalization, if $b=a-1$, the sum is $0$ irregardless of $f$.